# Add js file with parametar in Tapestry

Tags: java, javascript, maps, tapestry

I want to add google maps js lib to my tapestry application, but tapestry doesn't allow me to send parameter.
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=ansdjaskdjaksdajskdaskda&sensor=true" sends
The reference to entity "sensor" must end with the ';' delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `[JavaScriptSupport#importJavaScriptLibrary][1]`. You can take a look at the [`GMap`](https://github.com/exanpe/exanpe-t5-lib/blob/master/src/main/java/fr/exanpe/t5/lib/components/GMap.java) component.